# Prove that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ defining an one-to-one and onto function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proving that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ is a straightforward task with many instructional videos available online. However, I am attempting to create a function that maps each element of the first set (on the left side of the equation) to the second set (on the right side of the equation) in a one-to-one and onto manner. If I can identify such a function, the size of the two sets will be equivalent. What approach should I take to define this function?

Comment: What set do you have on the right hand side? I don't see a set there.

Comment: Why this $A + B - A \cap B$ is not a valid set?

Comment: What do the operators $+$ and $-$ mean in the context of sets?

Comment: First of all, how do you define addition and subtraction of sets? But even if it had a meaning, the right hand side is still not $|A+B-A\cap B|$.

Comment: Thank you, @Mark , for pointing this out. I failed to notice that the equation involves the sizes of four distinct sets, rather than just two.